# Conda UnsatisfiableError xgboost installation on Windows incompatible with cuda

Tags: python, conda, xgboost

Command used to install which is failing. There are no version currently getting installed on Windows 10.

`conda install dask-xgboost`

Environment Details:

```
conda 4.8.4
Python 3.7.7
```

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
>
> - feature:/win-32::__cuda==10.2=0

**Complete conda environment information**

```
(oto) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda info -a

     active environment : oto
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\XX\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\XX\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/mndrake/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/mndrake/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/legendu/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/legendu/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\XX\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\XX\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
                         C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2
base                     C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
oto                   *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto

sys.version: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [...
sys.prefix: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
sys.executable: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
conda location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-debug: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-debug.exe
conda-develop: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-render: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-render.exe
conda-server: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-skeleton: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
conda-verify: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-verify.exe
user site dirs: C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_BAT: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: oto
CONDA_EXE: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_EXES: "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (oto)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_ROOT: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 1
CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH: C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins
GIT_LFS_PATH: C:\Program Files\Git LFS
HOMEPATH: \Users\XX
NVTOOLSEXT_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
PATH: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\devprogs\java\jdk8u252-b09\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\libnvvp;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\devprogs\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin;C:\devprogs\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin;C:\Program Files\FMEServer\Utilities\jre\bin\client;C:\Program Files\FMEServer\Server\fme;C:\Program Files\FMEServer;C:\Program Files\Cloud Foundry;C:\devprogs\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\bin;C:\Program Files\MIT\Kerberos\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Airtame;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\FME;C:\devprogs\release-1900-x64-gdal-2-3-1-mapserver-7-2-0\bin;C:\hadoop;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin;C:\codelab\groovy\groovy-2.5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\devprogs\terraform_0.12.12_windows_amd64;C:\Program Files\FME19;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\XX\scoop\shims;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\bin;C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto
PSMODULEPATH: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PYTHONPATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\oto\;
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

Comment: Any idea where the `win-32` is coming from? Are you intentionally constraining to the **win-32** subdirectory? E.g., do you have `CONDA_FORCE_32BIT` or `CONDA_SUBDIR` set (this is uncommon)?

Comment: @merv Variable set as CUDA_PATH = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2 , ANACONDA_DIR=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3; CUDA_PATH_V9_2=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2